# Setting Up Project Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, ms-project

I am trying to set up a project online site for my organization. As part of it, I was able to create a project(Enterprise project) and then activated a SharePoint site.

I added my team as resources and assigned them as resources for few tasks(Also added them to project under build team).

But my team cannot see the tasks that were assigned to them. I can see the tasks under tasks on my account but not on their account.

Do I have to modify some setting to automatically assign tasks once they are assigned as resources?

**My goal** is

- to assign tasks to my teams and they should be able to look into the task and report the time they spent on it on their timesheets.
- Once the task is done I want them to close the task and me as a manager should be able to approve it.
- But none of the online resources are showing any setup processor settings that are essential for this process to work.

It would help if someone can guide me to some setup instructions.

Comment: Are you published your project after assigning the resources  ?

Comment: Yes, it is published

Comment: Do they have licenses assigned?

Comment: Yes all the users have licences assigned. I rechecked.